# php: Add value to exsiting key in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
$my_array = ["name" => "John", "email" => "example@example.com"]
```

I want to add one or more value to the "email". What I want to achieve is:

```
$my_array = ["name" => "John", "email" => "['example@example.com', 'example2@example2.com']"]
```

Is there a way to push it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, but you should be clear that it's what you want to do.  If you change the datatype of any part of your program there could be unexpected knock on effects (e.g. does your program check if `$my_array['email']` is a string or an array)

```
$my_array = ["name" => "John", "email" => "example@example.com"];

// if $my_array[email] is originally defined as a string
// convert the value to an array and include the original value
$my_array['email'] = [$my_array['email'], 'mynewvalue@email.com'];

var_dump($my_array);
/**
array(2) {
    ["name"]=> string(4) "John"
    ["email"]=> array(2) {
      [0]=> string(19) "example@example.com"
      [1]=> string(20) "mynewvalue@email.com"
  }
}
**/

// if it's always an array just push the value in
$my_array = ["name" => "John", "email" => ["example@example.com"]];
$my_array['email'][] = "someothervalue@email.com";


var_dump($my_array);
/**
array(2) { 
    ["name"]=> string(4) "John" 
    ["email"]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> string(19) "example@example.com" 
        [1]=> string(24) "someothervalue@email.com" } }
 */
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You cleared everything. In my case, it can always be an array. Sorry for not mentioning it in the question by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with something like this:

```
<?php
$my_array = ["name" => "John", "email" => "example@example.com"];

if (!is_array($my_array["email"])) {
    $my_array["email"] = [$my_array["email"]];
}

$my_array["email"][] = "second@example.com";

var_dump($my_array);
```

Firstly, we check if our key "email" already an array, and if not - convert it to array.
Then we just push new value to our key.

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a function that will allow you to send your array, value, and key you are searching for. If the key is found and there's a single string it will then convert to an array and add the new value. Otherwise it will append to the array.

```php
function addToArray($my_array, $value, $search)
{
    foreach ($my_array as $key => &$val) {
        if ($key === $search) {
            if (is_array($val)) {
                array_push($val, $value);
            } else {
                $val = [$val, $value];
            }
        }
    }

    return $my_array;
}

$my_array = ["name" => "John", "email" => "example@example.com"];
$my_array = addToArray($my_array, "test@example.com", 'email');
$my_array = addToArray($my_array, "Chad Smith", 'name');

var_dump($my_array);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["name"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "John"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "Chad Smith"
  }
  ["email"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(19) "example@example.com"
    [1]=>
    string(16) "test@example.com"
  }
}
```

The function allows you to pass in other emails as they become available.

Comment: This definetely worked. But, is there a way if the initial array doesn't have the "email" key? I mean what if the array was just `$my_array = ["name" => "John"]`

Comment: Then you would just call `$my_array = addToArray($my_array, "Chad Smith", 'name');` whatever key you know exists is what you would use for the last param. Looks like you accepted another answer which is narrow in focus but solves your issue.

Comment: Yeah, it solves my particular issue pretty easily. I appreciate your answer very much. Thank you